# How do I replicate the faux bold look without turning the resulting text into raster?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I designed some cards, but the text came out a little fuzzy when they came back from the printer.  In the end, this was because the text was rasterized in my submitted file, which was necessary because I enabled the "Faux Bold" style on the text.

I **like** the look that faux bold provides in my design.  How can I replicate look of faux bold without necessitating rasterizing the text when I export the file?  By what % does faux bold change the thickness and spacing of the letters, and what else does that style do to text?

I'm using Photoshop CS5 (Extended).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replicate faux bold pretty closely by applying 105% horizontal scaling in the Character pane, and a 1px centered Stroke (in the same color as my text) Layer Effect.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Sometimes faux bold really is the only way to get a certain look one wants and it is great that the option to use it is there. For most applications one wants to be careful using it, at least one should know about the implications. Just for curiosity, there is a quite recent great article up on [a list apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/say-no-to-faux-bold/) for you web designers regarding faux bold settings.